Charecterization of normal equivalence (convex polytopes).
Call two convex polytopes (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) normally equivalent if their normal fans coincide. For example it is immediate that if $P$ is a polytope then $\lambda P + x$ is normally equivalent for $\lambda > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Is there a nice characterization of normal equivalence? I have seen some results that used the linear constraint representation of polytopes, but I in particular interested a characterization in terms of the extreme points.
